# Silent Install of Oracle using WiX

Tags: oracle, installation, wix, custom-action, silent

I am creating an Installer using WiX, and as part of this I am installing Oracle also.
I am using CA for doing this. But it fails without executing.

```
<CustomAction Id="InstallORA" ExeCommand="[ORACLE]start-oraclexe-install.bat" Directory="ORACLE" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />
```

My bat file content is:

```
C:\xe-10.2.0.1-nt.exe /s /f1"C:\OracleXE-install.iss" /f2"C:\oraclexe-setup.log"
```

In logs I see `MSI (s) (44:9C) [12:18:42:344]: Running as a service.` after this it pops an error message.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Impersonate="no" means installation is being run under the SYSTEM service account, not under the user account. This is really a bad idea anyway, you should use a bootstrapper instead.

Comment: Hi, I have used burn.exe(thanks to saschabeaumont), for bundling my exe and msi. But can i install any one based on user selection, and can i take input from burn created UI and pass it on to msi inside.